# How to put the result from a column in the top of the result?

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have this sql:

```
SELECT x, y FROM table WHERE x = 'a' OR y = 'a'
```

In the result it will show something like this:

NOTE: the letters bellow represents the value returned from the column `x` and `y`.

a = x

b  = y

```
a
b
b
a
b
```

I want to get the results from the column `x` first. Like this:

```
a
a
b
b
b
```

Is it possible? The only way i found was to make two sql for both column and then use `UNION`;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use conditional logic in the `group by`:

```
SELECT x, y
FROM table
WHERE x = 'a' OR y = 'a'
ORDER BY (x = 'a') DESC;
```

MySQL treats a boolean value like an integer, with `0` for false and `1` for true.  Hence the `DESC` so the true values are first.

Answer (score 0):

Below answer is considering you are using SQL Server.

```
SELECT x FROM table WHERE x = 'a'
union all
SELECT y FROM table WHERE y = 'a'
order by 1
```

in the order by clause, 1 represents first column. Alternatively you can replace it with column name.